# how to check expected result matches any of give values in rspec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, tdd

How can we assert a value that matches any of `[1, 3, 5, 6, 10]`?

I am looking something like `matches_any_of([1, 3, 5, 6, 10])`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could do:

```
describe 'thing' do
  it 'includes' do
    expect([1,3,5,6,10]).to include(3) #or your resulting variable
  end
end
```

In answer to your comment, you could write a custom matcher or you could just do something like:

```
describe 'thing' do
  it 'includes' do
    i = 3
    results = [1,3,5,6,10].keep_if { |el| el == i }
    expect(results).to_not be_empty
  end
end
```

Comment: Actually I want other way round something like `expect(1).to matches_any_of([1,3,5,6,10])`

Answer (score 2):

I think you're looking for [RSpec's built-in `include`](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/docs/built-in-matchers/include-matcher) matcher:

```
expect([1, 3, 5, 6, 10]).to include(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

I hacked like this

`expect([1, 3, 5, 6, 10].include?(result).to be_truthy`